# How can I make smooth wrist for my Minecraft character?

Tags: rigging

[image]

I'am making a Minecraft character rig now i am stuck at a point i am trying to make smooth minecraft wrist I have properly weight paint the hand but still this problem is coming

BLEND FILE -( https://drive.google.com/file/d/145cymAEMZMk8wafRGlaUhjPT_v_GodvJ/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: You could segment your bones but as John MC says, it would be better if we could test

Comment: @MartyFouts:  i can see vertex groups and weight paints...